# FullCalendar, modify calendar on eventMouseover/eventMouseout

Tags: fullcalendar

https://fullcalendar.io

I have a need to render a background event when mousing over calendar events. Each calendar event has a datetime range associated with it that I would like to display on the calendar when the user hovers the mouse over it (and subsequently remove the background event from the calendar on eventMouseout). However, I've ran into an issue where the eventMouseover and eventMouseout events are triggered multiple times over and over when attempting to modify the fullCalendar on mouse enter/leave. I imagine this has something to do with the calendar being re-rendered when <s>any of its events are touched</s> adding/removing events to the calendar.

If you take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cbergman/pen/xPEbXG), open up DevTools and watch the console as you move your mouse over/out of any of the calendar events. If you move your mouse back and forth within an event you'll see the over/out events firing back to back, over and over.

What I'd like to have happen is a backgroundEvent (such as the following) to be updated with the datetime range on any given event. Then on mouseout, remove the backgroundEvent from the calendar.

```
// I'm only here because StackOverflow requires code to be present when a codepen link is shared.
var bgEvent = {
    id: -1,
    start: null,
    end: null,
    rendering: 'background',
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  };
```

Instead what happens is the eventMouseover fires, renders the event, followed by the eventMouseout, which immediately removes the event.

EDIT 1:

I'm in the middle of creating a scheduling app, and the calendar events essentially represent individual tasks belonging to a greater "appointment" object. Thus, when hovering over an individual "task" I desire to display its associated "appointment" range on the calendar to assist the user in deciding whether that task can be moved to a different date/time or not.

EDIT 2:

Submitted [an issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3914) on FullCalendar's github repo. Will update with any developments from there.

CODE FROM THE ABOVE CODEPEN

**HTML**

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
  var calendar = $('#calendar');

  var bgEvent = {
    id: -1,
    start: null,
    end: null,
    rendering: 'background',
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  };

  calendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
      console.log('in');
      bgEvent.start = event.start;
      bgEvent.end = event.end;
      var events = calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', bgEvent.id);
      if (events.length) {
        var e = events[0];
        calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', e);        
      }
      else
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', bgEvent);
    },
    eventMouseout: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
      console.log('out');
      calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', bgEvent.id);
    },
    defaultDate: '2017-11-06',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2017-11-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2017-11-07',
        end: '2017-11-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-11-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2017-11-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2017-11-05',
        end: '2017-11-07'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-11-06T10:30:00',
        end: '2017-11-06T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2017-11-06T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2017-11-06T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2017-11-06T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2017-11-06T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Movie',
        start: '2017-11-07T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2017-11-28'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

Comment: "the calendar being re-rendered whenever any of its events are touched". Full re-rendering doesn't happen when you hover an event, as far as I know. "I'm only here because StackOverflow requires code to be present when a codepen link is shared" That's because, as per stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, enough code should be within the question itself to make the problem reproducible. External links can change, disappear etc over time. The question should be usable by itself. It's not just trying to annoy you! Demos are a useful extra, but you can also use a StackSnippet within SO for that, too

Comment: Anyway, that behaviour you're seeing with the mouse events is not particularly helpful, IMO. Perhaps worth asking the fullCalendar people if it's a bug. https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Reporting-Bugs/ . In the meantime, perhaps worth considering whether what you want can be achieved by another  means. Can this info be displayed at all times? It's not clear why you want to add a background event directly underneath the actual event? What are you trying to achieve? Or, does it need to be a mouse event? Can it be a click on the event?

Comment: The calendar isn't being re-rendered on mouse over, no; it's when adding a new event (the background event) to the calendar. That's when the repainting is occurring.
In my actual use case I don't want to draw a background event directly underneath the one that's hovered over (although that could potentially be the case) - that was just a contrived example using FullCalendar's simple template they provided for reporting bugs.

Comment: I may need to go a different route if this one is a lost cause, and will likely report it to the fullCalendar people, too. Figured I'd ask good ol' trusty SO first, though.

Answer (score 1):

Adam Shaw from the FullCalendar project [comments](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3914) that "whenever any events are rendered or rerendered, ALL events are rerendered. What you are seeing is a flash rerender of the foreground event causing a real mouseout. When [#3003](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3003)'s optimization is made, this will be fixed."