# Fullcalendar changing the color of an event when mouseover another event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

What I'm trying to do is to change the color of an event when I put the mouse over another event. For example when I hover over event 58335 the color of 58345 to be changed from orange to blue.

[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVXw7.png)

I'm using eventMouseover event - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventMouseover/ but cannot figure out how to access another event. I tracked the jsEvent hoping that I can find some reference to the other events but couldn't find any.

Any suggestions? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: any example somwhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access other events, you can use the "clientEvents" method, which can retrieve any or all of the events currently visible on the screen. It can be supplied with a filter to restrict the results to specific events according to your requirements. Then you can use the "updateEvent" method to tell the calendar to update that event with its new values.

Here's the eventMouseover function:

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
  if (event.id == 58335) {
    var targetEvents = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", 58345); //restrict to event(s) with the ID specified in the second argument
    targetEvents[0].backgroundColor = "blue";
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", targetEvents[0]);
  }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/106/ for a working demonstration.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/ for more details of the fullCalendar methods used.

Presumably when you mouse out you want to change the colour back the original? If so then you can follow the same approach with the eventMouseOut callback.

Comment: Many Thanks! This helped a lot! The problem is with eventMouseout... this events fires even when the mouse is over the event, which is really strange and annoying. So maybe I need a different approach. Thanks again for this one!

Comment: @kmignt This is a peculiarity with fullCalendar unfortunately, caused by modifying an event during a mouseout, because this causes a full redraw of the calendar, which in turn causes more events to be triggered. There are plans to fix it, but no timescale that I know of. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47205756/5947043 and the links to the Github pages contained within it